# Xcode archive getting cached react native ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, xcode12

The debug build is working fine. It shows the current and updated code but when I'm creating a build in release mode or archive, it's showing some older version of the app. I tried cleaning the build folder multiple times, restarted Xcode and the machine multiple times but nothing seems to be working.

Xcode version: 12.4 (12D4e)
OS: macOS Big Sur(version 11.3)
RN verison: 0.63

Comment: are you archiving using Xcode or react native vs code?

Comment: @msusare I'm archiving it using Xcode(12.4)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-bundling first

```
react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.js --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios --platform ios
```